# .NET 7 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

This is my first time asking around here, so sorry if it's not worded very well. 
I have a blazor WebAssembly project with MudBlazor, and when I try to upload files to save them into a database, it appears the next error message in the browser console. 
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file`

When the user uploads the files I call the next method to save the files into `IList<IBrowserFile>`.

```
IList<IBrowserFile> Files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
private void OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            Files.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Once the user has uploaded all the files, they click on a button that call the next method to upload it into a database.

```
[Inject] protected ISnackbar Snackbar { get; set; } = default!;
private async void Upload()
    {

        List<string>? notUploadFiles = null;
        foreach(var file in Files)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(destPath + file.Name);
            string extn = new FileInfo(file.Name).Extension;

            var addArchivoTarea = new AddArchivoTareaRequestDTO(Tarea.Id, fileBytes, extn);
            var successResponse = await HttpTareas.AddArchivoToTareaAsync(addArchivoTarea);

            if (!successResponse)
            {
                notUploadFiles.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }

        if(notUploadFiles is not null) {
            Snackbar.Configuration.SnackbarVariant = Variant.Filled;
            Snackbar.Add("The following files could not be uploaded:", Severity.Info);

            Snackbar.Configuration.SnackbarVariant = Variant.Outlined;
            foreach (var file in notUploadFiles)
            {
                Snackbar.Add(file, Severity.Error);
            }

            //Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.TopCenter;
            //Snackbar.Add("TODO: Upload your files!", Severity.Normal);
            MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
        }

        Snackbar.Add("All files have been successfully uploaded", Severity.Success);
        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
    }
```

I don't know where is the problem, any idea?

Comment: Because you have not upload file to physical storage, The file still in the memory, So you can't use that way to manipulate it. In  general, you can save the file as the type of byte[] in database, More information you can refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-upload-scenarios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploaded files are not in the file system, they are in-memory only. The way to access the raw data would be something like:

```
        byte[] fileBytes;

        using (Stream s = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            await s.CopyToAsync(ms);
            fileBytes= ms.ToArray();
        }
```